# How do I play real media videos on a mac?

Tags: realmedia

I want to play a Real Media (.rm) video on my Mac. VLC Player (Version 2.0.3 Twoflower (Intel 64bit)) won't play it. Neither would Quicktime.

Do I have to download Real Media Player to play a real media video on a Mac? I probably won't need Real Media Player ever again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, downloading Real Media Player is the easiest way. You could mess with converting it to another format if you wanted, but I don't see how that would be easier/more beneficial. You can just delete Real Player when you are done with it.